# build ionic application giving error

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework

I want to build my ionic project. I tried ionic build android but it showing me an error Failed to find `ANDROID_HOME` variable.

Here is my `.bashrc` file contents.

## Android path

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/bridgeit/Android/android-sdk-linux
export PATH=$PATH:/home/bridgeit/Android/android-sdk-linux/tools
export PATH=$PATH:/home/bridgeit/Android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:/home/bridgeit/Android/android-sdk-linux/
```

but i am still getting error Failed to find `ANDROID_HOME` variable.

Comment: Well, have you set the ANDROID_HOME system environment variable?

Comment: nope.please suggest me how to do it

Comment: Did you Google how to do it? Which part of those tutorials were you having trouble with?